# Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@2.2.0

Tags: node.js, webpack, dependencies, peer, uglifyjs-webpack-plugin

Here is details of my error:
My node version is **16.13.0** and npm is **8.12.1**.

```
PS D:\ShowCase> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@2.2.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.51.1
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^5.47.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"4.x.x || 5.x.x" from @webpack-cli/configtest@1.0.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@webpack-cli/configtest
npm ERR!     @webpack-cli/configtest@"^1.0.4" from webpack-cli@4.8.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/webpack-cli
npm ERR!       dev webpack-cli@"^4.7.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       3 more (@webpack-cli/configtest, @webpack-cli/info, @webpack-cli/serve)
npm ERR!   8 more (babel-loader, css-loader, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@2.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!   dev uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@"^2.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@2.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     dev uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@"^2.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Please let me know if anyone has faced the same problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` will work fine with **Webpack 4** but will not work with **Webpack 5**. Since this plugin is not scheduled for Webpack 5, You better downgrade Webpack from 5 to 4. Or Try other plugins like `babel-minify-webpack-plugin` or `terser-webpack-plugin` to minify javascript if you want to use `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` specifically to minimize javascript code.

---

You can check the last stable release of [`uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin) was 3 years ago, and no documented development support for Webpack 5.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response, I will check your suggestion.

Comment: `babel-minify-webpack-plugin` seems not to work with webpack ^5 either 
```
peer webpack@"^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0" from babel-minify-webpack-plugin@0.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Tried updating webpack and even installed yarn but it didn't seem to work, furthermore when I tried installing a new version of webpack-cli it threw a similar error.
What I did was changing the version of webpack-cli manually on the package.json to the latest today (5.1.4) and I could finally install and run everyting else.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).